# How can I get requirements.txt to work for Google App Engine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-logging, requirements.txt

It appears the current versions of google-cloud-logging and google-cloud-storage are incompatible. How on earth does Google think it's okay to have a "platform" where you can't use the latest versions of things together?

If my requirements.txt has:

```
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-logging
```

I get:

```
WARNING: Found incompatible dependencies: "google-cloud-datastore 1.15.5 has requirement protobuf<4.0.0dev, but you have protobuf 4.21.7
```

If I try to work around that by adding:

```
protobuf==3.20.1
```

Then I get:

```
WARNING: Found incompatible dependencies: "google-cloud-logging 3.2.5 has requirement protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1.\ngoogle-cloud-appengine-logging 1.1.6 has requirement protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1.\ngoogle-api-core 2.10.2 has requirement protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1.
```

Does anyone here know an incantation that actually allows google-cloud-storage and google-cloud-logging to be used *at the same time*?

Also, if anyone from the GAE team is reading this, will you *please* get your act together on this, and make the "latest" versions of your SDKs work together? This protobuf issue has been around for a really long time.

Comment: Why did you specify `3.20.1` instead of less than 4.0? This is not a Google Cloud support site. Google does have a site for issues, bugs, and feature requests here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: I used 3.20.1 because that's what I was advised to use the last time this happened. You're right: "protobuf<4" eliminated the warning. Thanks! (You could offer it as an answer, and I'll check it.) The GAE team has a long history of telling users to ask questions on StackOverflow, which is why I started here.

Comment: I do understand the confusion regarding support. The issue is "free" community support and official support (paid). Google does motivate GDEs ( Google Developer Experts) to contribute (donate) time to help solve problems on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are integrating Cloud Datastore, which has a dependency requirement that the `protobuf` package version be lower than 4.0 use:

```
protobuf<4
```